# How can I make an exact 60FPS GIF?

Tags: video, after-effects, animation, animation-rendering, export

I'm trying to create a 60FPS GIF. However if I use Photoshop the frame time is not correctly even when choosing 0 delay between each frame.

I was trying to make an emote.

The project is from After Effects.

I've tried various tools, here is my only problem:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmjKK.jpg

The background color I used is #36393F

for some reason though, it has some weird grid around it, so it isn't the clean background which I need it to be. And yeah not sure how to make 60FPS GIFs now. I can not use WebP, it is not supported, that's why I need a background behind it.

I've tried various tools, XMedia Recorder, doesn't have GIF export at all.

GIFGun, the one with the grid issue. I've tried it in another project with any moveable object, the same issue.

ezgif, well that one could work if it had 60FPS.

Here is the .AVI file if anybody wants to try out something: https://workupload.com/file/4Fbdyt5g

The reason why I need it exactly to be 60fps, is because otherwise it doesn't match the length.

Comment: Answered at https://superuser.com/q/1449366

Comment: Indeed, I can make 50FPS GIF's with ffmpeg

Answer (score 1):

The gif format doesn’t work like this. You won’t be able to get an animation with this high a frame rate.

The good news is that many sites which claim to use GIFs actually use mp4 files. I don’t know your exact workflow, but you could  try making an mp4 at this frame rate and uploading it to one of the “GIF” sites.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as 60fps GIFs.

GIF files store delay time between frames in whole hundredths of second, so it's impossible to make a GIF with exactly 60fps, because value 1 would give you 100fps and 2 would already have half of that - 50fps. Besides that, many programs (including Google Chrome) ignore value 1 and defaults to much slower animation speed when viewing such files, so 100fps GIFs, while technically possible according to file format, are not commonly used and probably a bad idea, so value 2 (50fps) is the most you can get.